# Pandas - check if ALL values are NaN in Series

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan, series

I have a data series which looks like this:

```
print mydf

id_L1
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7       NaN
8       NaN
```

I would like to check if all the values are `NaN`.

My attempt:

```
pd.isnull(mydf).all()
```

Output:

```
True
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: yes, `isnull` will create a boolean series, `all` returns `True` if all are `True`

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, but I think a more idiomatic way would be:

```
mys.isnull().all()
```

Answer (score 23):

This will check for all columns..

```
mys.isnull().values.all(axis=0)
```

Comment: This is the right approach if you are searching "check if ALL values are NaN in DataFrame", like me. OP was searching for the Series solution Tho :P 

**EDIT** I prefer the version giving as result a Series: `opp.isna().all()`

Comment: I would add '[0]' at the end to get to the actual "False" or True":         
 mys.isnull().values.all(axis=0)[0]

Answer (score 1):

```
if df['col'].count() > 0:
    then ...
```

This works well but I think it might be quite a slow approach. I made the mistake of embedding this into a 6000-times loop to test four columns - and it's brutal, but I can blame the programmer clearly :)

Obviously, don't be like me. Always: Test your columns for all-null once, set a variable with the yes - "empty" or no - "not empty" result - and then loop.