# Pandas - If all values of dataFrame are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

How to create an if statement that does the following:

```
 if all values in dataframe are nan:
     do something 
 else: 
     do something else
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147158/pandas-check-if-all-values-are-nan-in-series), one can check if all the values of a DataFrame are NaN. I know one cannot do:

```
if df.isnull().all():
    do something
```

It returns the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Need another `all`, because first `all` return `Series` and another `scalar`:

```
if df.isnull().all().all():
    do something
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=list('abcde'))
print (df)
     a    b    c    d    e
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

print (df.isnull())
      a     b     c     d     e
0  True  True  True  True  True
1  True  True  True  True  True
2  True  True  True  True  True
3  True  True  True  True  True
4  True  True  True  True  True

print (df.isnull().all())
a    True
b    True
c    True
d    True
e    True
dtype: bool

print (df.isnull().all().all())
True

if df.isnull().all().all():
    print ('do something')
```

If need faster solution - [`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) with [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html), but first convert all values to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print (np.isnan(df.values).all())
True
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.full((1000,1000), np.nan))
print (df)

In [232]: %timeit (np.isnan(df.values).all())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

In [233]: %timeit (df.isnull().all().all())
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop

In [234]: %timeit (df.isnull().values.all())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop
```

Comment: > np.isnan(df.values).all() results in: 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isnan'

Answer (score 5):

Faster improvement on jezrael's would be `df.isnull().values.all()`

```
In [156]: df.isnull().values.all()
Out[156]: True
```

---

**Benchmarks**

small

```
In [149]: df.shape
Out[149]: (5, 5)

In [150]: %timeit df.isnull().values.all()
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop

In [151]: %timeit df.isnull().all().all()
1000 loops, best of 3: 271 µs per loop
```

large

```
In [153]: df.shape
Out[153]: (1000, 1000)

In [154]: %timeit df.isnull().values.all()
10 loops, best of 3: 26.6 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit df.isnull().all().all()
10 loops, best of 3: 40.8 ms per loop
```